# Create Autosizeble panel with panels inside

Tags: asp.net, extjs, coolite

Sorry for not very clear question title, but maybe image will help to describe my ploblem:

[image http://my.jetscreenshot.com/2951/20100604-ioyo-164kb.jpg](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/2951/20100604-ioyo-164kb.jpg)

I want small child panels in parent panel to be autosizeable. Here is my markup and codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bkg = new[] { "background-color: wheat;", "background-color: gray;", "background-color: #AAAAAA;" };
            var random = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < 285; i++)
            {
                var panel = new Panel
                                {
                                    Header = false,
                                    Width = 60,
                                    Height = 30,
                                    BodyStyle = bkg[random.Next(0, 3)],
                                    Frame = false,
                                    StyleSpec = "padding-top: 1px; padding-left: 1px;",
                                    ID = "panel_" + i,
                                    Html = string.Format("<span class='x-unselectable'>{0}</span>", i)
                                };
                var cell = new Cell();
                cell.Items.Add(panel);
                TableLayout1.Cells.Add(cell);
            }

        }

<ext:Panel ID="pnlWorkArea" runat="server" Title="Test">
    <Body>
        <ext:TableLayout ID="TableLayout1" runat="server" Columns="15">
        </ext:TableLayout>
    </Body>
</ext:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want the child panel arrangement to completely fill the center region, there's not a simple way to do that other than calculating the inner dimensions of the region, then assigning fixed height/width to the child panels as you are now, but based on your measurements.  You could do this either by handling the `render` event or overriding `onRender` of the center region panel.

If the number of rows and columns is always the same you could try using % dimenstions, but in my experience that does not work consistently across browsers (you can get small gaps sometimes due to rounding from decimal percentages to pixels).